# When are stock trade fees deducted?

Tags: stocks, trading, fees

When you buy or sell stock with an online broker when are the trading fees (approx. $7 or $10) deducted from your available balance?  Is it when the order is placed? At the end of the month?

Comment: What country and what broker ... it varies.

Comment: As @Dheer says, it varies. I think most brokerages deduct any commissions and fees when the order is *filled* (not placed, an order can be placed and filled months apart), but there are some where a flat monthly fee gives you a certain number of trades, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the fees are charged when the order is executed.

The only catch I have ever ran into is when an order is partially executed. A good-till-cancel order that gets executed in several blocks over multiple days may get charged a separate commission for each day (but typically not each block).

If this is a simple brokerage account, you could avoid the whole question by using robinhood.com, which charges no commissions or maintenance fees.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it depends on the brokerage firm.

My broker is Scottrade. With Scottrade the commission is assessed and applied the moment the order is filled. If I buy 100 shares of XYZ at $10 a share then Scottrade will immediately deduct $1007.02 out of my account. They add the commission and fees to the buy transaction. On a sale transaction they subtract the commission and fees from the resulting money. So if I sell 100 shares of XYZ at $11 a share I will get 1,092.98 put into my account, which I can use three business days later.

Comment: How exactly do they add/subtract to the transaction? Do they give you less shares or for example trade for higher rate?